# How do I get a value associated with a user model class property for login redirection with access token?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm, access-token

**UsuarioModel Class**

```
public class UsuarioModel
    {
        public int CodUsuario { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Senha { get; set; }
        public string Telefone { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataRegisto { get; set; }
        public bool Estado { get; set; }
        public int CodPerfil { get; set; }
    }
```

**Login ApiService Method**

```
public async Task<string> LoginAsync(string nome, string senha)
        {
            var keyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", nome),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", senha),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password")
            };

            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, Constants.BaseApiAddress + "token");
            
            request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValues);

            var client = new HttpClient();

            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            JObject jwtDynamic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(content);

            var accessTokenExpiration = jwtDynamic.Value<DateTime>(".expires");
            var accessToken = jwtDynamic.Value<string>("access_token");

            Settings.AccessTokenExpirationDate = accessTokenExpiration;

            Debug.WriteLine(accessTokenExpiration);

            Debug.WriteLine(content);

            return accessToken;
        }
```

> This method works correctly by generating the access token. But my question is: how can I get the value of the 'CodPerfil' of this user who received the access token to validate the Menu that he should be directed to?

**ViewModel**

```
public class LoginViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {

        private readonly ApiServices _apiServices = new ApiServices();

        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Senha { get; set; }

        public ICommand LoginCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(async () =>
                {
                    var accesstoken = await _apiServices.LoginAsync(Nome, Senha);
                    Settings.AccessToken = accesstoken;
                    Login();
                });
            }
        }

        public async void Login()
        {
            var usuario = new UsuarioModel
            {
                Nome = Nome,
                Senha = Senha,
                CodPerfil = CodPerfil
            };

            Settings.CodPerfil = CodPerfil;
            if (CodPerfil == 1)
            {
                App.Current.MainPage = new MenuMorador();
            }
            else
            {
                App.Current.MainPage = new MenuRecolhedor();
            }
        }

        public LoginViewModel()
        {
            Nome = Settings.Nome;
            Senha = Settings.Senha;
        }
```

> When I execute this method through the breakpoints, the 'CodPerfil' variable does not receive any value. The question is: How to receive the value of the 'CodPerfil' property that is associated with the user already registered in order to validate the menu to which they will be directed after receiving the access token?

**Startup Class**

```
public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        }

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            //this is very important line cross orgin source(CORS)it is used to enable cross-site HTTP requests  
            //For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests  
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

            var OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(10),//token expiration time  
                Provider = new OauthProvider()
            };

            app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthOptions);
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);//register the request  
        }
    }
```

**OauthProvider Class**

```
public class OauthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    {
        public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
        {
            await Task.Run(() => context.Validated());
        }

        public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);

            using (var db = new DataContext2())
            {
                if (db != null)
                {
                    var user = db.Usuario.Where(o => o.Nome == context.UserName && o.Senha == context.Password).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.CodPerfil.ToString()));
                        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Nome));
                        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("LoggedOn", DateTime.Now.ToString()));
                        await Task.Run(() => context.Validated(identity));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        context.SetError("Wrong Crendtials", "Provided username and password is incorrect");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    context.SetError("Wrong Crendtials", "Provided username and password is incorrect");
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: do you expect the login token to contain your UsuarioModel?  Or do you expect LoginAsync to return both a token AND UsarioModel?

Comment: Complicated question ... But I want LoginAsync to return both and pass IF condition.
The first option may also work but I don't know how to implement it. Please say what seems most feasible to you.

Comment: so this is really a server issue - you could easily create a wrapper class that contains the token and the model, or make a 2nd call to retrieve the model once you've received the token.  There are lots of options.

Comment: I tried to make this second call using the 'Login ()' method but the problem is: how to get these values ​​already authenticated after getting the access token?

Comment: you should be including the token in every call in order to authenticate

Comment: You said there are lots of options but still doesn't show one properly... Can you give an simple example of how to get the 2nd call to retrieve the model after I get the token??

Comment: I don't know anything about your API or what methods it supports so there is no way for me to give you a concrete example.  I assume there is some method like `GetUserProfile` that you would call after you login that would return the details you need.

Comment: I have already updated the question and added the code for the Web class API Startup.cs that provides the token and OAuthProvider, if you can take a look I would appreciate it.